# Is it possible to run multiple ASP.NET Core projects in single applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Consider I'm having two ASP.NET Core MVC Web projects.

- **Project A** - will have accounts and user information. (Not a class library)
- **Project B** - will get account information from project A

Project A can be run individually.

Project B & A can be combined and run as single application

Is it possible to handle this in ASP.NET Core? If yes, what is the beast approach?

[Like this (This is a ASP.NET MVC app)](http://arunendapally.com/post/how-to-use-a-mvc-area-in-multiple-applications)

Comment: Did you even try to do this in .Net Core? Anyway, that tutorial is pretty bad - I wouldn't do it like that.

Comment: @DavidG I've not tried this. But looking for best approach to do this.

Comment: Then maybe you should try it and learn while you're doing it. Stackoverflow is not a place to ask about best practices I'm afraid, that's off topic here.